# Issue with libMonoPosixHelper.dylib when compressing a string on unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, compression

I'm working again on an old project that used to build and work fine with Unity 2018.3

I've installed Unity 2019.3.0f3.

I can build without issue (unless I've missed something in a log somewhere?).

I have the following function:

```
public static string CompressString(string text)
        {
            try
            {
                if (text == null || text.Length == 0) return String.Empty;

                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
                    using (var gZipStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
                    {
                        gZipStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    }

                    memoryStream.Position = 0;

                    var compressedData = new byte[memoryStream.Length];
                    memoryStream.Read(compressedData, 0, compressedData.Length);

                    var gZipBuffer = new byte[compressedData.Length + 4];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(compressedData, 0, gZipBuffer, 4, compressedData.Length);
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(BitConverter.GetBytes(buffer.Length), 0, gZipBuffer, 0, 4);

                    return Convert.ToBase64String(gZipBuffer);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception erreur)
            {
                return text;
            }
        }
```

Which works fine on windows.

When I try on my mac I get the following exception:

> CompressString : libMonoPosixHelper.dylib : : : at (wrapper
>   managed-to-native)
>   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStreamNative.CreateZStream(System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode,bool,System.IO.Compression.DeflateStreamNative/UnmanagedReadOrWrite,intptr)
>   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStreamNative.Create (System.IO.Stream
>   compressedStream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode mode,
>   System.Boolean gzip) [0x0004a] in :0
>   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream..ctor (System.IO.Stream
>   compressedStream, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode mode,
>   System.Boolean leaveOpen, System.Boolean gzip) [0x0002d] in
>   :0   at
>   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream..ctor (System.IO.Stream stream,
>   System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode mode, System.Boolean leaveOpen,
>   System.Int32 windowsBits) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream..ctor(System.IO.Stream,System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode,bool,int)
>   at System.IO.Compression.GZipStream..ctor (System.IO.Stream stream,
>   System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode mode, System.Boolean leaveOpen)
>   [0x00006] in :0   at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   System.IO.Compression.GZipStream..ctor(System.IO.Stream,System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode,bool)
>   at LibTRANSVERSE.Helper.String_Utils.CompressString (System.String
>   text) [0x00028] in <3ae6905998594b6a999ad880754f3bfd>:0
>   UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String,
>   Object) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String,
>   Object[]) UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
>   UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>   LibTRANSVERSE.Helper.Monitoring:Exception(Exception, String)
>   LibTRANSVERSE.Helper.String_Utils:CompressString(String) ...
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper:ThreadStart_Context(Object)
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext:RunInternal(ExecutionContext,
>   ContextCallback, Object, Boolean)
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext:Run(ExecutionContext,
>   ContextCallback, Object, Boolean)
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext:Run(ExecutionContext,
>   ContextCallback, Object)
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper:ThreadStart(Object)   (Filename:
>   ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

Am I missing something? Is it an issue with Unity or is it me using a function not available on mac?

Comment: With "When I try on mac" do you mean when running your project in the editor on a mac, when trying to build on a mac, or running your build application on a mac?

Comment: I mean by building (for mac from my pc) and launching the build on a mac.